# Retrieve android.intent.extra.EMAIL value from bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I created one app like email clients app such as **Gmail**.

When user click on email address in another apps and choose my app from email sending apps in list appear on .

The email content like email address , email subject and .... come to my app by intent .

But the problem is `intent.getData();` is `null` value all of the time and i try to get email data from `intent`  .

I tested `bundle` in `intent`  and i saw its not null and when i write this code :

```
bundle = intent.getExtras();
                Log.e("Email",bundle.toString());
```

the `bundle.toString()` return  `Bundle[{android.intent.extra.EMAIL=[Ljava.lang.String;@11cda76c}]` .

I dont know what is this `[Ljava.lang.String;@11cda76c}]` and how i can get the email address from here ! ?

Comment: this is similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881033/get-string-from-bundle-android-returns-null

Comment: @camahalanroyette i think this link about how to get special bundle when we create it . but i dont know what is bundle content . only i can recive it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer here [Passing values through bundle and get its value on another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022274/passing-values-through-bundle-and-get-its-value-on-another-activity)

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String email= bundle.getString("EMAIL");
```

**Edit:**

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String [] emails=bundle.getStringArray(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL );
```

Comment: Thanks but  `bundle.getString("EMAIL")` returned me a null value .

Comment: if you read my question exactly . i didn't create any bundle . only i receive it from another apps and now i want to access its content.

Comment: I searched and found that extra email is an array so try `String [] emails=bundle.getStringArrayExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL ); `

Comment: the bundle class have no method named : `getStringArrayExtra` i used this code :  `String [] emails= bundle.getStringArray(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);` when i print emails it show me something like this string : `[Ljava.lang.String;@2244b9ca` . do you know what is this ?

Comment: I'm sorry it's **getStringArray** instead of **getStringArrayExtra**

Comment: ok i used this to convert it to string thank you for help  `Arrays.toString(email array from bundle);` pls edit you answer i accepted your answer .

Comment: Emails in bundle are stored in array because it might contain one or more email recipient so converting to string maybe a problem when two or more recipient will be passed to your intent